# Stored Procedure renders no data in table viewer and model

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, qlikview

I have a model in qlikview with DB2 files, xls files and SQL views.
All my views return no errors, all with data.

I used a stored procedure for some data(a list of items with no data in some days. The SP uses inserts to temp table, cursors and joins).
In SQL server management studio returns normal results
Example results for stored procedure

[image]

In Qlikview, i tried with:

```
centrosCostosSinDatos:
SQL GRANT Execute ON SP_nameStoredProcedure to qlikviewReader;
```

This return no data, no table in table viewer, no dimensions, nothing, but, i don't have error.

With **load**, have error **Field not found - < codigoCentroCosto >**

```
centrosCostosSinDatos:
LOAD codigoCentroCosto,
fecha;
SQL GRANT Execute ON SP_nameStoredProcedure to qlikviewReader;
```

With **load ***, i have error **Error: File extdata.cpp. Line 2903**

Thanks for advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I test again.

Changed my stored prcedure for use a table and not a temporal table. In execution, the table has not rows.

I grant execute permissions to the user (qlikviewReader) in the database server, and change the execute line:

```
centrosCostosSinDatos:
SQL GRANT Execute ON SP_nameStoredProcedure to qlikviewReader;
```

to

```
centrosCostosSinDatos:
LOAD codigoCentroCosto as codeCentroCosto, 
fecha;
SQL execute SP_centrosCostosSinDatos;
```

and works. Load * works too.

In my case, **grant execute not works**. **Permissions in Stored procedure for this user it works**.